# Generating download code from an images ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview which list all of the images from my database. The image table in my database contains, amongst other things, ID (Primary Key) and FileExtension (.jpg, .png, .gif). In each listview item I will have a download icon, which when clicked needs to download the correct image to the user's browser. This seems easy, if they click on the download icon for image with ID of 2, they will download 2[FileExtension], but I have no idea how to code this.

Here's the relevant bit of my aspx:

```
<asp:ImageButton Runat="server" ID="ibtDownloadImage" ImageUrl="img/downloadIcon.png" />
```

It's currently an ImageButton control but it can change if needs be.

Here's my code behind for that page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

DataClasses1DataContext PiccyPic = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var images = from i in PiccyPic.Images
                     select i;

        lvwImages.DataSource = images;
        lvwImages.DataBind();


    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }


    protected void ibtDownloadImage_OnClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;
        String imgURLtoDownload = sender.CommandArgument;

        Response.TransmitFile(imgURLtoDownload);
    }
```

You can see I haven't filled in the very last line, because I have no idea what to put in there to reference the ID and FileExtension.

Here's what each listview item looks like. The Image, Image Title, Image Description, uploaded by, and downloads are all retrieved from the database using #Eval statements.

The image is retrieved by doing

```
<img src = "img/uploads/<%#Eval ("ID") %><%#Eval ("FileExtension") %>" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you call `ibtDownloadImageDefine(sender, e);` in the Page_Load ? you can delete this line I think.

What you need is to use an *OnClick* method, to have an action when you click on the button.
Then, for the URL of image to download, you can bind the *CommandArgument* :

```
<asp:ImageButton Runat="server" ID="ibtDownloadImage" OnClick="ibtDownloadImage_OnClick" ImageUrl="img/downloadIcon.png" CommandArgument='<%#Eval ("ID") %> + "|" + <%#Eval ("FileExtension") %>' />
```

and in the code-behing, implement the *OnClick* method, for example :

```
protected void ibtDownloadImage_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;
   String[] argument = img.CommandArgument.Split(Convert.ToChar("|"));

   String ID = argument[0].ToString(); 
   String FileExtension = argument[1].ToString();

   String imgURLtoDownload = "img/uploads/" + ID + FileExtension; 

   Response.TransmitFile(imgURLtoDownload);

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but that still leaves me with the problem. The problem is that I need to construct the download URL from the ID and the FileExtension, which are two columns in a database, and I don't know how to reference them.

Comment: Look the code of ImageButton, I referenced them into the CommandArgument of the ImageButton with Eval("ID") and Eval("FileExtension")

Comment: Missed that, my bad. Added it in now, but the Code Behind can't find CommandArgument ("'object' does not contain a definition for 'CommandArgument' and no extension method 'CommandArgument' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)")

Comment: I think you badly implemented it. Plz edit your post with the actual code asp and code-behind.

Comment: I would like the asp code plz (your listview + ImageButton)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63937/discussion-between-dramixx-and-frayt).